# Sky City dystopian film, similar to Alita: young female robot befriends scavengers and discovers she used to be a warrior from the sky city

Tags: story-identification, movie, animation

The film I need help finding is set in a dystopian future where humans coexist with cyborgs/robots. The protagonist is a young female who gets dumped down the trash chute and falls to ground level where the entire city is covered with parts and trash. When she lands an old man finds her and repairs her broken parts. When she wakes she finds herself among a group of scavengers who become her friends. One of the scavengers takes a liking to her and they fall in love.

Later she discovers that she is from the sky city and wants revenge for what they did to her. The scavengers take her out of the city to see the old war relics and she discovers she was a warrior in a previous life.

That’s all I can remember so far and recently I went to see *Alita*. The movie was basically a 1:1 of the film I’m describing. I even went as far as watching the original *Alita* and still it wasn’t it.

Comment: Apart from the protagonist being a girl, it sounds a lot like the Astro Boy movie. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astro_Boy_(film)

Comment: Do you remember if it was live action or animated, and if animated, whether it was 2D or 3D?  Astro Boy sounds plausible if it was 3D.

Comment: I just watched some trailers and clips from Astro Boy and that’s not it either. It looks similar, but it’s missing the floating city and the female protagonist. For the second question, yes it was a 3D animated film.

Comment: Do you recall when you saw the movie, and/or what country?  Do you recall what format you saw it in? (dvd/cable/theater/?)

Comment: Could it be [this](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt8601988/)?

Comment: Sky City certainly seems like it would have been worth posting as an answer...

Answer (score 8):

Is it possible that you're remembering seeing the [original video adaptation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_Angel_(OVA)) from 1993?

I have yet to watch the 2019 production - but I enjoyed the 1993 anime quite a bit, and so have been looking forward to the new movie. From what I understand, while there was extra backstory added to some of the main of the main characters, and some of the characters were changed - the main beats of the story were [kept](https://screenrant.com/alita-battle-angel-movie-differences-anime-changes/) [intact](https://geektyrant.com/news/watch-the-full-original-battle-angel-alita-anime-movie-and-see-how-much-alike-it-is-to-the-live-action-film).

[image]

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding something in this answer, the last line in the question does state _"I even went as far as watching the original Alita and still it wasn’t it."_

Comment: @Jenayah thanks - I missed that line... I'll leave the answer to stand, though - as I know some people who weren't/aren't aware of the OVA

Answer (score 3):

Could this be ***[Sky City](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt8601988/)*** (2017)?

This CGI video short was mentioned in a comment. It fits the time frame and the description also matches quite nicely.

> A science fiction CG animation depicts a deserted future earth world
> through CG technology. The rich people abandoned the ground and moved
> to skycity. A scavenging girl on the ground helps a robot who has
> fallen from the Skycity to go back to it's home.

Unfortunately there don't seem to be any copies that can viewed on the Internet and there don't seem to be any useful references to this film other than IMDB.

Given that the director and [producer](https://www.animafest.hr/en/2009/category/grand_competition/jia_duan) (who appears to also be the only speaking cast member) are both film school professors, it's likely that this was some sort of proof-of-concept production.

Comment: I've contacted the producer and the director to see if they have copies they can share.